# Category Issue Magento 2.3 (Porto Theme)

Tags: magento2.3, category, porto-theme

We have an issue with Category (www.lsxgarasjen.no).
We have 2 subchild categories ( so the path is Motordeler Og tuning - AN koblinger og Slanger) If wee try to go to the next step the next box (not sure what to call ut, sorry) disappears and you need to go through all the steps again.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Porto theme 3.2.1 and Magento 2.3. Megsmenu extension

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You broke the styling.  Change the Left : 100% to Left 95%, to give you a bit more overlap so it doesn't disappear on mouse over

Comment: Also looks like there is an issue somewhere in the AJAX code.  Moving the menu over helps, but whenever you move down the list there is a refresh and that also closes the menu.  I am hacking you code though in a browser, so might do better changing it at source

Comment: hi can you share ne url?

Comment: @jan-petter Havna It is css issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Anthony, do you mean to change the left subchild boarder on left from 100% to 95%?

Comment: @Sarvesh, can you see where in the CSS code there is an issue? I have the same theory as Anthony is saying regarding the boarder.

Comment: ok I can tell you

Comment: just share ftp details please

Answer (score 0):

Is sorted now, it was a something to do with the CSS. Created a support ticket @Porto and they send me a new line of code to add and works perfectly now.